# Trazer o valor do rotulo/label de um model

Tags: python, django

Eu preciso trazer o valor 'Nome do atributo' que está no model para a minha view.

Alguém sabe me dizer como eu chamo esse valor de lá?

```
class LogDetalhe(models.Model):
    atributo = models.CharField('Nome do atributo', max_length=200, null=False, blank=False)
    ds_valor_anterior = models.TextField('Descrição valor anterior')

View:

Logdetalhe.atributo....
```

Fiz várias tentativas sem sucesso. Deve ser uma coisa simples, mas não tá saindo.

Answer (score -1):

Olá, também estou aprendendo Django então caso minha resposta não seja muito completa ou legível, já peço desculpas.

Algumas das possíveis causas esteja relacionada a view. De um modo geral, temos que para importar os valores de atributo e ds_valor_anterior na sua view seria assim:

> Na Model:

```
class LogDetalhe(models.Model):
          atributo = models.CharField('Nome do atributo', max_length=200, null=False, 
blank=False)
          ds_valor_anterior = models.TextField('Descrição valor anterior')
```

> Na sua view:

```
from .models import LogDetalhe #não se esquecer de importar a classe

def valor_atributo:
      valor_atributo = LogDetalhe.objects.all()
      #se for utilizar para um simples render:
      return render(request, 'home/pagina.html', {'valor_atributo'}:valor_atributo)
```

> Na urls.py

```
path('pagina1/', views.valor_atributo, name="pagina1")
```

> Exemplo no html para somente puxar o atributo

```
<div>{{valor_atributo.atributo}}</div>
```

Só lembre de sempre fazer os imports da sua view e models nos lugares corretos. Espero que tenha ajudado em algo.

Answer (score -1):

Uma maneira de resolver o problema é criando um form para o seu model.

Como já possui um model a maneira mais simples de fazer isso é utilizar a classe [ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/forms/modelforms/)

Vou mostrar como pode implementar utilizando essa estratégia:

```
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm


class LogDetalhe(models.Model):
    atributo = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, blank=False)
    ds_valor_anterior = models.TextField()


class LogDetalheForm(ModelForm): 
    class Meta:
        model = LogDetalhe
        fields = ["atributo", "ds_valor_anterior"]
```

Depois em seu `views.py` crie uma instância do ModelForm e passe via context para o seu template:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from .models import LogDetalheForm, LogDetalhe

def index(request):
    logd = LogDetalhe.objects.all().first()
    instancia = LogDetalheForm(instance=logd)

    context={
        "instancia": instancia
    }
    return render(request, 'logdetalhe/index.html', context)
```

Agora a resposta para o que realmente perguntou, se quer pegar a informação do `label` do atributo ela está presente na instância através do atributo `label`.

Em seu template `logdetalhe/index.html` você deve ter o seguinte código (escrito  na linguagem de template):

```
<p><strong>{{ instancia.atributo.label }}: </strong> {{ instancia.atributo.value }} </p>
<p><strong>{{ instancia.ds_valor_anterior.label }}: </strong> {{ instancia.ds_valor_anterior.value }} </p>
```

---

Lembrando que também é possível renomear o atributo da maneira que fez em seu código, porém toda vez que fizer essa mudança será necessário executar um makemigrations e aplicar as migrations.

Mudança no model:

```
class LogDetalhe(models.Model):
    atributo = models.CharField('attr',max_length=200, null=False, blank=False)
    ds_valor_anterior = models.TextField('valor_anterior')
```

Isso é possível através dos comandos:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

A saída esperada deste comando:

```
python manage.py makemigrations

<app>/migrations/0003_alter_logdetalhe_atributo_and_more.py
- Alter field atributo on logdetalhe
- Alter field ds_valor_anterior on logdetalhe
```

Depois executar o migrate:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

Saída esperada deste comando:

```
Operations to perform:
   Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions
```

Running migrations:
Applying .0003_alter_logdetalhe_atributo_and_more... OK

Depois em seu template o alias do campo será renderizado:

```
Attr: abc
Valor_anterior: def
```

---

É possível também mudar o label do campo em tempo de execução, para isso basta você personalizar o campo `labels` da subclasse do ModelForm (para o seu caso é a classe `LogDetalheForm`) da seguinte forma:

```
class LogDetalheForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = LogDetalhe
        fields = ["atributo", "ds_valor_anterior"]
        labels = {
            "atributo": "Meu nome de atributo personalizado",
        }
```

Para mais informações consulte a [documentação](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/)